# Expo : Accelerometer.isAvailableAsync() doesn’t work?

Tags: react-native, expo, accelerometer

In my React Native App I use Accelerometer from Expo and I would like to use the function Accelerometer.isAvailableAsync() to check if accelerometer is supported. But it doesn’t work.
Someone would have a solution ?

Here is my code :

```
import { Accelerometer } from 'expo';

...

isAccelerometerAvailable(){

    Accelerometer.isAvailableAsync()
    .then(
      result => {
        this.setState({
          isAccelerometerAvailable: String(result)
        });
      },
      error => {
          this.setState({
            isAccelerometerAvailable: "Could not get isAvailable: " + error
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Post some code to check what could be the problem.

Comment: It's good I edited my request

Comment: Show how you import Accelerometer

Comment: It's done, I edited my request

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
isAccelerometerAvailable(){

    Accelerometer.isAvailableAsync()
    .then(
      result => {
        this.setState({
          isAccelerometerAvailable: result
        });
      },
      error => {
          this.setState({
            isAccelerometerAvailable: "Could not get isAvailable: " + error
        });
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: It's doesn't work... Here is error message : `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _expo.Accelerometer.isAvailableAsync is not a function. (In '_expo.Accelerometer.isAvailableAsync()', '_expo.Accelerometer.isAvailableAsync' is undefined)]`

Comment: Did you find solution to it?